# empty list check for python(looping error)

Tags: python

## I want to output the message "No more biscuits are left" if the list is empty

## I tried, but it keeps on looping(because of the while loop) can you help me fix this

```
more = input('\nWould you like a biscuit (Y/N)... ')

while more != 'N':

    if len(biscuits) != 0 :
        choice = random.randint(0,len(biscuits)-1)
        print('Your biscuit is : ', biscuits[choice])
        del biscuits[choice]
        more = input('\nWould you like a biscuit (Y/N)...')
    else:
        print("No more biscuits are left")

print('\nThere are ', len(biscuits), ' biscuits left.')
print('\n', biscuits, '\n')
```

Comment: after `else:` add `break`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull both conditions into the `while` loop:

```
more = input('\nWould you like a biscuit (Y/N)... ')

while more != 'N' and biscuits:
    choice = random.randint(0,len(biscuits)-1)
    print('Your biscuit is : ', biscuits[choice])
    del biscuits[choice]
    more = input('\nWould you like a biscuit (Y/N)...')
if not biscuits:
    print("No more biscuits are left")

print('\nThere are ', len(biscuits), ' biscuits left.')
print('\n', biscuits, '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

use break after printing and it will break out from the loop and finish.

```
else:
    print("No more biscuits are left")
    break
```

Comment: Is there another way without using break?

Comment: instead of break you can also set more to 'N": more='N' and it will automatically get out from the loop

Answer (score -1):

In python, an empty list will have the boolean equivalent of `False` so you can simply do:

```
if not biscuits:
    print("No more biscuits are left")
    break
```

Comment: This will give you infinite loop when list is empty.

Comment: I'm just doing whats pythonic; infinite loops that are just broken is not very pythonic. Some revision of the code seems in order.